# How can I trace module dependencies in Features?

Tags: features

I have a site with several module created with the Features module. I've just noticed that one of the modules created with Features (we'll call it module B), has a dependency on another module created with Features (module A). As far as I know, there should be no connection or dependency between the two modules at all.

Is there a way to track down which aspect of feature B is creating the dependency on feature A since I'm almost positive it is doing so in error?

Answer (score 1):

Look through the info file of Feature B and look for anything known to be added or modified with Feature A.

My guess (with little information) would be that Feature A defines a field/cck field and Feature B either uses that in a content type or view.